# Vector Tiles: Considering a rule, change each building color of Buildings layer

Tags: mapbox, vector-tiles, mapbox-gl

I'm consuming a Mapbox hosted map with Mapbox GL (but if needed, I can use leaflet or whatever) that has the standard Mapbox street layers including OSM Buildings layer plus a custom layer uploaded by me with the shapes of the zip codes of a country.

**Question:**
I have 10 zip codes and I want to have each of them with a different color, so 10 colors. The buildings inside each zip code will receive their respective zip code color, so I will have 10 groups of buildings. How can I do that?

I know that I could create my own layer of buildings already classifying the buildings. But I think this won't be possible because actually, I want to use buildings of a whole country, so I would end up with a huge layer. If I manage to define the color of each building intersecting on-the-fly as they load, then I can still use OSM Buildings layer provided by Mapbox.

Any ideas?

Comment: The upcoming setFeatureState feature (https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/blob/60aaa4f0e1b5412e0cffb77ded5d3dabcc1b07a9/docs/pages/example/data-join.html) might help. When you have new base tiles come in, do a turf query to determine which zip code polygon it's in, then set a feature state for it. Then use expressions to style.

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely try this. Is there any estimation on when this is going to be available?